# Solve for variables that look in a certain way

Tags: equation-solving

I often have to use Solve and I'm wondering if I there is a more efficient way to specify which variables I have to solve for.
Say that I have

```
eqs = Table[
    x[a, b, c] + y[a, b, c] + a + b + c == 0, {a, 1, 3}, {b, 1, 
     3}, {c, 1, 3}] // Flatten;
```

If I call `Solve[eqs]`, it will solve for the `y` in terms of the `x`. But if I want to solve for the `x` in terms of the `y`, instead, I need to call

```
Solve[eqs, 
 Table[x[a, b, c], {a, 1, 3}, {b, 1, 3}, {c, 1, 3}] // Flatten]
```

Is there a simpler way, without having to explicitly build the table of the `x` variable? I tried something like `Solve[eqs, x[_,_,_]]` or variations of it but couldn't find anything that works. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Solve[eqs, Cases[eqs, _x, All]]
```

> ```
> {{x[1, 1, 1] -> -3 - y[1, 1, 1], x[1, 1, 2] -> -4 - y[1, 1, 2], 
>  x[1, 1, 3] -> -5 - y[1, 1, 3], x[1, 2, 1] -> -4 - y[1, 2, 1], 
>  x[1, 2, 2] -> -5 - y[1, 2, 2], x[1, 2, 3] -> -6 - y[1, 2, 3], 
>  x[1, 3, 1] -> -5 - y[1, 3, 1], x[1, 3, 2] -> -6 - y[1, 3, 2], 
>  x[1, 3, 3] -> -7 - y[1, 3, 3], x[2, 1, 1] -> -4 - y[2, 1, 1], 
>  x[2, 1, 2] -> -5 - y[2, 1, 2], x[2, 1, 3] -> -6 - y[2, 1, 3], 
>  x[2, 2, 1] -> -5 - y[2, 2, 1], x[2, 2, 2] -> -6 - y[2, 2, 2], 
>  x[2, 2, 3] -> -7 - y[2, 2, 3], x[2, 3, 1] -> -6 - y[2, 3, 1], 
>  x[2, 3, 2] -> -7 - y[2, 3, 2], x[2, 3, 3] -> -8 - y[2, 3, 3], 
>  x[3, 1, 1] -> -5 - y[3, 1, 1], x[3, 1, 2] -> -6 - y[3, 1, 2], 
>  x[3, 1, 3] -> -7 - y[3, 1, 3], x[3, 2, 1] -> -6 - y[3, 2, 1], 
>  x[3, 2, 2] -> -7 - y[3, 2, 2], x[3, 2, 3] -> -8 - y[3, 2, 3], 
>  x[3, 3, 1] -> -7 - y[3, 3, 1], x[3, 3, 2] -> -8 - y[3, 3, 2], 
>  x[3, 3, 3] -> -9 - y[3, 3, 3]}}
> ```

Also (when `eqs` is linear in `x[...]` and `y[...]`):

```
Solve[eqs /. x -> z] /. z -> x
```

> same result